# Grafana: Bug showing All series in a Graph

Tags: python, grafana

I’m using Simple Json as datasource for visualize a simple graph with 2 series. This is my query from Query Inspector:

[image]

And this is the graph that I retrieve (after few customizations)

[image]

As you can see I think there is a visualisation bug with the option “All series”. In fact, if I move hover a point near the middle (like in the picture), the graph shows the values associated at the last point. Furthermore, If I move hover a point to the right of the middle, the graph shows the values of the first point.

I’m using Grafana v6.4.3 and SimpleJson 1.4.0

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened the same issue on the Github page of Grafana:https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/19989

The problem was the sorting order of my data-points. The all-series option works only if your date are sorted in ascending order (in my case they was sorted in desc order).

Now it works perfectly.